# What value of $c$, if any is the function continuous at $x=3$?

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

At first, I equated the first and last pieces of the function, plugged in 3 for $x$ and got 6. But then I realized that neither are defined at 3 so it made me think that maybe the answer is that there's no such value for $c$ that will make the function continuous since it'll still be undefined at $x=3$ for the first and last pieces. Which is correct?

Comment: I don't understand why you say the first and last pieces are undefined at $x=3$.  Both of those are perfectly well defined at $x=3$ and, as you say, they'd be equal at $x=3$ if and only if $c=6$. So now you have to ask if taking $c=6$ makes the function continuous at $x=3$ or not.

Comment: @lulu if c were 6, the function would not be continuous at x = 3? Because of their domains?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with their domains.  Continuity requires that you test their behavior near $x=3$.

Comment: @lulu So it means that c is truly equals c to make the function continuous?

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  The posted solution is perfectly sound...I suggest studying that.

Comment: I meant c is truly equal to 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** If it were continuous at $x = 3$, you must have
$$
\lim_{x \nearrow 3} c + c x - x^2
= 7
= \lim_{x \searrow 3} 2 c + \frac{3}{x - 2}
$$

Comment: Does that mean the limit at x = 3 must be 7 for it to be continuous?

Comment: @harpey1111 Yes. There must exist a $c$ such that the limit from both sides is 7.

Comment: I got it. I think there is no value for c that will make the function continuous since the system c+3c-9=7 and 2c+3/(3-2) = 7 is inconsistent (no solution). Is this right?

Comment: @harpey1111 Yes, the first equation gives $c = 4$ and the other $c = 5$, a contradiction. Notice that if you replace 7 by 15, the function would be continuous.